# Include () method not loading in some conditions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I have the following EF query :

```
var result = (from t in context.Tickets.Include("Priority").Include("Status")
                                           where t.TicketOpenBy.Id == user.Id
                                           select t).Include(t => t.TicketOpenBy);
```

I also try

```
context.Tickets.Where(t => t.TicketOpenBy.Id == userId).Include("Priority").Include("Status").Include("TicketOpenBy");
```

When i receive the list, for each row, the object "TicketOpenBy"  has all fields null.

But when i change the "where" with this condition :

```
"where t.TicketOpenBy.Id != user.Id"
```

I receive my object with all properties included.

I don't understand this behaviour. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `t.TicketOpenBy.Id` a foreign key to `User`? Or is `TicketOpenBy` a `User`?

Comment: Yes TicketOpenBy is a User and t.ticketOpenBy.Id is a FK.